# How to pass null value to mysql stored procedure using java

Tags: mysql

Below is my stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE `addRecord`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addRecord`(company varchar(3000),name                 
varchar(3000),title varchar(3000),metro varchar(3000),city varchar(3000),email  
varchar(3000),phone varchar(3000),industry varchar(3000))

BEGIN

    insert ignore into record_data (company,name,title,metro,city,email,phone,industry)        
            values(company,name,title,metro,city,email,phone,industry);
END
```

My main task is to check duplicate entries. It works fine if i provide some values to all the fields. But if i provide certain field as null from java it inserts an new row.Rather than eliminating duplicate.
    **For e.g.**

```
   if i use following statement it dosent insert an entry if it exists

   record.addRecord("abc", "a", "abc", "a","b","ostwal@gmail.com", "518- 220", "intl");

   but if use 
   record.addRecord("abc", "a", "abc", null,null,"ostwal@gmail.com", "518- 220", null);
   it inserts another row even if it already exists.
```

Comment: allow null to the fields in which you are inserting null valus..alter your table

Comment: i have allowed null values...

Comment: are you assigning default values as well or not

Comment: by default each column of table is set to null

Comment: use `NULL` not `null`

Comment: or tell me the fileds in which you are assiging `null` having what kind of datatype.

Comment: @rahul :: in java u cannot pass NULL , u need to use null as its an keyword specifying null values...

Comment: @rahul :: all the columns are varchar() with default value null

Comment: you can do one thing the columns having `null` value don't include them in your insert query.

Comment: thank you all for your valuable suggestions. & sparing time for this post..